# Kotlin HashMap contain keys using an array

Tags: hashmap, kotlin

Is there any way to check a HashMap if it contains a certain set of keys which keys are given in an array. When I try something like the code below it returns false.

```
map.containsKey(arrayOf("2018-01-16"))
```

If I try the following code it works but I need to check for the keys and the numbers of keys that I need to search is not fixed.

```
map.containsKey("2018-01-16")
```

Comment: Do you want to return true if the map contains all of the keys or just any of it?

Comment: If it contains all the keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start from the keys themselves, and use the [`all`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/all.html) function from the standard library:

```
val map = hashMapOf(...)
val keys = arrayOf("2018-01-16", "2018-01-17", "2018-01-18")
val containsAllKeys = keys.all { map.containsKey(it) }
```

---

If you do this a lot and want to have this functionality on the `Map` type, you can always add it as an extension:

```
fun <K, V> Map<K, V>.containsKeys(keys: Array<K>) = keys.all { this.containsKey(it) }

val containsAllKeys = map.containsKeys(arrayOf("2018-01-16", "2018-01-17"))
```

You might also want to overload the extension with another function that takes an `Iterable<K>` as the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

`Map` has `keys` collection, which as every collection implements `containsAll` method, so you can use it to check whether the `keys` collection contains all of the keys:

```
map.keys.containsAll(keysArray.asList())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ArrayList<T>` as a key, since it's equals is different as the `Array<T>` one. Let's see this test:

```
class ExampleUnitTest {
  @Test
  fun arrayAsKeyTest() {
    val hashMapOne = HashMap<Array<String>, Int>()
    val stringKeysOne1 = arrayOf("a", "b")
    hashMapOne.set(stringKeysOne1, 2)
    val stringKeysOne2 = arrayOf("a", "b")
    // NOT MATCH! As stringKeysOne1 == stringKeysOne2 is false
    assertFalse(hashMapOne.containsKey(stringKeysOne2)) // NOT MATCH

    val hashMapTwo = HashMap<ArrayList<String>, Int>()
    val stringKeysTwo1 = arrayListOf("a", "b")
    hashMapTwo.set(stringKeysTwo1, 2)
    val stringKeysTwo2 = arrayListOf("a", "b")
    // MATCH! As stringKeysTwo1 == stringKeysTwo2 is true (although stringKeysTwo1 === stringKeysTwo2 is false)
    assertTrue(hashMapTwo.containsKey(stringKeysTwo2)) // MATCH
  }
}
```